# response data to $_SESSION?

Tags: php, javascript, session

I am pushing some data in to my javascript array every 30 seconds.This data comes comes via ajax response.I want to use this array on the next page I visit without its content being lost.

```
setInterval(function () {
      $.ajax({
                url: "../controller/controller_session.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {data to send},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                     ARRAY.push(JSON.stringify(data))
        },30000)
    }
```

How do I transport this data using $_SESSION to some other page on website and how do I retrieve it back and reuse it my javascript.

Comment: Maybe you could also use http://www.jstorage.info/

Comment: I am already using session storage.But I will use this as fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript cant read your session data, that is stored on the server and Javascript only manipulates the actual data what you have. You would have to make an AJAX call to another PHP page to get the `$_SESSION` and then send the data back to the AJAX success function.

On a PHP file have

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['value'])){
    $session = $_SESSION['value'];
}

echo isset($session) ? $session : '';
```

Then you call that page in an AJAX call and check to see if the page returned something.

EDIT:

```
success: function(data){
    $('.div').html(data);
}
```

Comment: can you give a small snippet

Comment: how do I use this $_session data back .i want to display it using innerHTML.

Comment: I wouldnt bother with datatype:json, in the success of the AJAX() function, it will be in the parameter of the success function.

Comment: Thanks,understood it.I will send request to my php page->set the session variable-->push data in it every 30 seconds-->then echo the $_SESSION and get that as response in my javascript...correct?

Comment: You can set it or get it, just process code on the PHP page and send back what you want to the success function in the AJAX call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33621/discussion-between-messiah-and-in-god-i-trust)

Answer (score 0):

Set the SESSION variable on **controller_session.php** page just before the return. Save the result as a string in your SESSION variable.

On the next page use the SESSION value (I guess it's a JSON string) parse it and use it in your JavaScript code.